# Join one table to another based on certain conditions met by rows in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. I want to create a SQL query such that for each row in Table 1, I want find the first two rows in Table 2 such ms.Table2 > ms.Table1. The resulting output will be Table 1 with six additional columns added showing ms, bid, ask from Table 2 corresponding to first two rows from Table 2 where ms is just greater than ms in Table 1.

Given the large number of rows, doing a cross-join and then filtering may be too much (since this has to be done many times over multiple data, not just once). Looking for an efficient solution. I am new to SQL so feel this is bit much for me, though I did try a cross-join. Please help!

Table 1 (2000+ rows)

| ms | price | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34200106 | 1.48 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34200106 | 1.48 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34202812 | 1.56 | 1.53 | 1.56 |
| 34202815 | 1.56 | 1.53 | 1.56 |
| 34202823 | 1.56 | 1.53 | 1.56 |
| 34204227 | 1.56 | 1.53 | 1.57 |
| 34207137 | 1.56 | 1.55 | 1.57 |
| 34208496 | 1.57 | 1.56 | 1.57 |
| 34208938 | 1.57 | 1.55 | 1.57 |
| 34208938 | 1.57 | 1.55 | 1.57 |
| 34208943 | 1.57 | 1.55 | 1.57 |
| 34208951 | 1.57 | 1.56 | 1.57 |

Table 2 (300000+ rows)

| ms | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34200009 | 1.46 | 1.51 |
| 34200011 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34200106 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34200171 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34200195 | 1.46 | 1.5 |
| 34200195 | 1.46 | 1.51 |
| 34200201 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200202 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200276 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200296 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200305 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200306 | 1.46 | 1.52 |
| 34200308 | 1.46 | 1.53 |
| 34200326 | 1.46 | 1.53 |

Comment: There are duplicate rows in table 1. Should a row be returned for each duplicate or only for each unique row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query produces the described results without doing a full cross join between table1 and table2:

```
SELECT table1.ms,
       table1.bid,
       table1.ask,
       t2.ms[1] AS ms1,
       t2.bids[1] AS bid1,
       t2.asks[1] AS ask1,
       t2.ms[2] AS ms2,
       t2.bids[2] AS bid2,
       t2.asks[2] AS ask2
  FROM table1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t.ms) AS ms,
                             ARRAY_AGG(t.bid) AS bids,
                             ARRAY_AGG(t.ask) AS asks
                        FROM (SELECT table2.*
                                FROM table2
                               WHERE table2.ms > table1.ms
                               ORDER BY table2.ms
                               LIMIT 2
                             ) t
                     ) AS t2;
```

Comment: Great solution. Quite fast relative to a full cross-join. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could use a loop, but it will still be somewhat slow, but much faster than a cross join

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ("ms" int, "price" int, "bid" int, "ask" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    ("ms", "price", "bid", "ask")
VALUES
    (34200106, 1.48, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34200106, 1.48, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34202812, 1.56, 1.53, 1.56),
    (34202815, 1.56, 1.53, 1.56),
    (34202823, 1.56, 1.53, 1.56),
    (34204227, 1.56, 1.53, 1.57),
    (34207137, 1.56, 1.55, 1.57),
    (34208496, 1.57, 1.56, 1.57),
    (34208938, 1.57, 1.55, 1.57),
    (34208938, 1.57, 1.55, 1.57),
    (34208943, 1.57, 1.55, 1.57),
    (34208951, 1.57, 1.56, 1.57)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 12
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE table2
    ("ms" int, "bid" int, "ask" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table2
    ("ms", "bid", "ask")
VALUES
    (34200009, 1.46, 1.51),
    (34200011, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34200106, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34200171, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34200195, 1.46, 1.5),
    (34200195, 1.46, 1.51),
    (34200201, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200202, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200276, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200296, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200305, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200306, 1.46, 1.52),
    (34200308, 1.46, 1.53),
    (34200326, 1.46, 1.53)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 14
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() 
RETURNS TABLE ("ms" int, "price" int, "bid" int, "ask" int)
  language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE 
  x int ;
  table1_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT t1."ms" FROM table1 t1; 
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS
    SELECT *
    FROM table1;

  FOR x IN table1_cursor loop
    INSERT INTO temp_table ("ms", "price", "bid", "ask")
     SELECT t2."ms", NULL, t2."bid", t2."ask" FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2."ms" > x."ms"
      ORDER BY t2."ms" 
       LIMIT 2;
  END loop;

RETURN QUERY 
SELECT t3."ms", t3."price", t3."bid", t3."ask"
from temp_table t3;
    DROP TABLE temp_table;

END $$;

SELECT * FROM foo();
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

| ms | price | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34200106 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 34200106 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 34202812 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34202815 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34202823 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34204227 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34207137 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34208496 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34208938 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34208938 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34208943 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34208951 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34200171 | *null* | 1 | 2 |
| 34200195 | *null* | 1 | 2 |
| 34200171 | *null* | 1 | 2 |
| 34200195 | *null* | 1 | 2 |

> ```
> SELECT 16
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hFhElFxo)

Comment: Wow, thanks nbk, looks it might do the trick. I will need to study it carefully.

Comment: It goes over all rows of table1 and checks table2 for two rows that are bigger than ms , but you nee to go over all rows of table1 as long as you don"t have a limit to table1